# Map in react native keep refreshing each time i move on it

Tags: javascript, react-native

i am trying to use map view in react native so the user can choose any place in the map and send that location to the back end ;
my problem is when i try to look for some place in the map, it refresh auto and back to the origin point(map Region) which prevent me from looking for place inside the map
how can i  prevent this auto refreshing from happening
this is my code below :

```
export default function MapScreen() {
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState();
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({
    coords: {
      ..
  });
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Platform.OS === "android" && !Constants.isDevice) {
      setErrorMsg(
        "Oops, this will not work on Sketch in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!"
      );
    } else {
      (async () => {
        let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== "granted") {
          setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
        }
        let userLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setLocation(userLocation);
      })();
    }
  });
  var mapRegion = {
    latitude: location.coords.latitude,
    longitude: location.coords.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.005,
    longitudeDelta: 0.005,
  };

  const selectLocationHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSelectedLocation({
      latitude: event.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude,
      longitude: event.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude,
    });
  };

  let markerCoordinates;

  if (selectedLocation) {
    markerCoordinates = {
      latitude: selectedLocation.latitude,
      longitude: selectedLocation.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0,
      longitudeDelta: 0,
    };
  }
  if (selectedLocation) {
    mapRegion = {
      latitude: selectedLocation.latitude,
      longitude: selectedLocation.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.005,
      longitudeDelta: 0.005,
    };
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        select your location
      </Text>
      <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        region={mapRegion}
        onPress={selectLocationHandler}
      >
        {markerCoordinates && (
          <Marker title="Picked Location" coordinate={markerCoordinates} />
        )}
      </MapView>
        </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: On which platform this is happening? Android or IOS?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan Android

Comment: Ok, let me have a look at that.

Comment: For starters, you don't have a dependency list in useEffect, add an empty array as the second argument. The way you have it set up, useEffect will run on every render, not just initially.

Comment: Use initialRegion props instead of region props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ToneCrate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8942505/tonecrate) gave you the correct answer in the comments by pointing out that your `useEffect` hook was missing the dependency array. I'm copying it here so the question will be answered:

> For starters, you don't have a dependency list in useEffect, add an empty array as the second argument. The way you have it set up, useEffect will run on every render, not just initially.

You can learn more about how to use the `useEffect` hook from the [official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).